# one problem from limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

How will I proceed for the question 63? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Change it to polar coordinates? so you have $\frac{r^{\alpha+\beta} (\sin\theta)^{\alpha} (\cos\theta)^{\beta}}{r}$

Comment: okk...Wht do u think wht will be the answer?@user160738

Comment: It's clear from the polar expression, it can't be anything else than 2. It is certainly contained in option 2 but it might not be equal. There's problem with 3 if $\alpha=-1$, say, since $x^{\alpha}=1/x$ is not even defined along the line $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a Multiple Choice Question, you can simply eliminate options.

Notice that if we replace $\alpha$ by $\beta$ and $\beta$ by $\alpha$, the expression is the same, I.e only the name of constants has changed. Hence we can conclude that the answer must be symmetrical w.r.t. $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Thus by rejecting options $(1),(2)$ and $(4)$ we get the answer - $(3)$

Comment: (1) and (2) are also symmetric; (3) doesn't work because it doesn't rule out nasty cases like $\alpha=-1$, when the expression isn't defined along $x=0$ (y-axis)

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ so that $lim_{r\rightarrow 0}f(r,\theta)=lim_{r\rightarrow 0}r^{\alpha +\beta-1}.[(cos\theta)^{\alpha}.+(sin\theta)^{\beta}]\rightarrow(0,0) \forall\theta$  iff $\alpha +\beta>1$.

Now it is easy to see that the set $S=${$(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb R^2:\alpha+\beta>1$} is contained in option $3$ .

Comment: What about the case $\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=3$? How is the expression defined along the line $x=0$ in this case?

Comment: it might be greater than > in last line..@toddler

Comment: yes...thanks @user160738 for pointing out my mistake..Edited

Comment: so 3 is correct  ? Are u sure..?@user160738

Comment: The correct option is 2, notice that $\alpha+\beta>1$ if both of these quantities exceed $2$. option (3) and (4) doesn't rule out the case I mentioned above

Comment: why -1 + 3 = 2 > 1 where is the problem?@user160738

Comment: @cmi I'm saying if $\alpha=-1$ then your original expression isn't defined along the line $x=0$ because you are dividing by $0$. But option (3) does not say it is impossible to say $\alpha=-1$, so it is wrong. Saying the expression converges to $0$ iff $\alpha+\beta>1$ is also wrong. But within option (2) it certainly does so (2) is only correct option. $\alpha>2$ and $\beta>2$ means $\alpha+\beta>4>1$

Comment: @user1607387...the question is assuming all $(\alpha,\beta)$ at which $f(x,y)$ is defined and limit exists equal to $(0,0)$ at the origin i.e. if you choose $\alpha=-1$ then $\beta>2$.

Comment: @user1607387 but question is asking which set contains S....option 2 definitely does not contain...But option 3 contains....

Comment: Am I not right? @user1607387